# Xray: Results Import Task Error assembling issue data: project is required

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, jira-xray

Starting to import execution results from cucumber.json: File: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/XRAY_TEST/target/cucumber.json
Starting to import results from cucumber.json
ERROR: Step ‘Xray: Results Import Task’ failed: Unable to confirm Result of the upload..... Upload Failed! Status:400 Response:{"error":"Error assembling issue data: project is required"}
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: Can you please share the cucumber json report file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error that you obtained probably is happening because the Cucumber JSON report doesn't contain tagged Scenario/Scenario Outline elements, containing the corresponding Test issue keys in Jira.
Usually this means that you didn't exported the Scenario/Scenario Outline from Xray, or else they would be tagged automatically and then the results could be mapped correctly to existing Test issues.

The supported workflows for Cucumber are described [here](https://docs.getxray.app/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=62267221#TestinginBDDwithGherkinbasedframeworks(e.g.Cucumber)-Workflows).
In general terms, you always need to have Test issues in Jira/Xray corresponding to the Scenario/Scenario Outline elements.
You can either decide to use Xray/Jira as the master for editing those or Git, for example; if you decide for the latter, you need to explicitly synchronize the Cucumber Scenario/Scenario Outlines to Xray (either using the REST API directly or Jenkins plugin for example).

[The tutorial for Cucumber (Java)](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/Testing+using+Cucumber+in+Java) explains the workflows and details the necessary tasks to implement.

Note1: it would be useful to have the Cucumber JSON report to have a look at its  contents, namelly the "tags" elements.
Note2: these links are for  Xray on Jira server/datacenter; for cloud, please check [Xray Cloud documentation](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/About+Xray) instead

Comment: Thank you Sérgio for your return, 
I solve the problem … in my case I’m working using filter ID no tags in my features files 
And the problem was the filter it’s private